# How do I unlock Play + mode?

Tags: thumper

On the main menu of *Thumper*, there is a grayed out option for a “Play +” mode. Apparently this is a more difficult “[director’s cut](https://www.polygon.com/2016/11/10/13582774/thumper-free-directors-cut-play-plus-update-playstation-4-pro-steam)” permadeath option which was added in a free update.

How do I unlock Play + mode? Do I need to beat the game first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[According to the official Thumper blog](https://thumpergame.com/blog/2016/11/8/play-mode-playstation-pro-support-and-more-updates):

> If you’ve already beaten the game, PLAY + mode is the ultimate test of your thumping skill. **If you’re new to the game, just beat Level 3 to unlock the new mode!**